# MediaWiki API revisions VS allrevisions

Tags: python, mediawiki-api, revision-history

I am trying to write a script in order to get the revision history of biographies (the goal is to investigate how a biography changes over time). I have read most of the related articles here and the documentation about the **revision** module but I can't get the results I want. I post my code, most of it is copied (partially or complete) from the documentation. I changed the value in the *titles* parameter.

Moreover, I found the **allrevisions** submodule. I made it to return revisions for a specific biography, but what I get doesn't related to the revision history that someone found on the page.

Code related to "revisions"

```
import requests
S = requests.session()
URL = "https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php"

PARAMS = {
    "action": "query",
    "prop": "revisions",
    "titles": "Albert Einstein",
    "rvprop": "timestamp|user|content",
    "rvslots": "main",
    "formatversion": "2",
    "format": "json"
}
R = S.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)
DATA = R.json()
print(DATA)
```

Code related to "allrevisions"

```
URL = "https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php"

    PARAMS = {
    "action": "query",
    "list": "allrevisions",
    "titles": "Albert Einstein",
    "arvprop": "user|timestamp|content",
    "arvslots": "main",
    "arvstart": "2020-11-12T12:06:00Z",
    "formatversion": "2",
    "format": "json"
}
    R = S.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)
    DATA = R.json()
    print(DATA)
```

Any suggestions to make it work properly? The most important is why the code related to "revisions" doesn't return anything.

As suggested, I want to get the full revision history for a specific page.

Comment: The answer came by changing this "https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php" with this "https://en.wikipedia.org//w/api.php" on the first code. And adding `rvlimit` param as @Tgr suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prop` modules return information about a specific page (or set of pages) you provide. `list` modules return information about a list of pages where you only provide some abstract criteria and finding the pages matching those criteria is part of the work the API is doing (as such, `titles` in your second example will essentially be ignored).

You don't explain clearly what you are trying to do, but I'm guessing you want to get the full page history for a specific title, so your first example is mostly right, except you should set a higher `rvlimit`.

See also the (unfortately not very good) doc on [continuing queries](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Example_4:_Continuing_queries) since many pages have a history which is too long to return in a single request.

Comment: Unfortunately, "rvlimit" doesn't change anything. On the same code if I change "Albert Einstein" to "Python" works.

Comment: Sure it does: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&action=query&titles=Albert_Einstein&prop=revisions&rvlimit=10

Comment: To my code above, if I add the "rvlimit" parameter, it doesn't even returns "revisions" in the response.